# Short is not working but int does?

Tags: c, int, short

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    short a, b, c;
    printf("Enter the values of a, b and c: ");
    scanf(" %d %d %d ", &a, &b, &c);
    if( a<b && a<c )
        printf( "a is smaller" );
    else if( b<a && b<c )
        printf( "b is smaller" );
    else
        printf( "c is smaller" );
    return 0;
}
```

For the input `a=10`, `b=12`, `c=13`, it gives the output "c is smaller"?

And when I replace the `short` with `int` it gives correct output.
I have also tried the `%h`, `%i` but it outputs the same.

What's going wrong?

Comment: It is UB, you are passing `short` instead of `int`, that is the type expected for `%d` format specifier

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Are you assuming `short` and `int` are the same width?

Comment: The simplest way to start finding out what's up is to print the values that the program read, to make sure that what the program read is what you expected it to read.  Add `printf("Data: a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c);` after you check that you got three values read by `scanf()`.

Comment: Read the documentation of `scanf` and other functions you use. Also enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them. If your compiler has no option to check `scanf`/`printf` format-strings, get a modern compiler.

Comment: When you say "also tried the `%h`", what do you mean?  Did you try `%hd`, `%hi`, or `%h` by itself?

Comment: Also, was there a specific reason you wanted to use `short`?  In most programs, most of the time, plain `int` is fine, and appropriate to use for general-purpose integers.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
scanf(" %hi %hi %hi ", &a , &b , &c);
```

`%d` is for `int` where as `%hi` is for `short` data types

Comment: And you should also clarify why you add **i** to the format specifier. Maybe OP doesn't want that.

Comment: Note that `%hi` will accept `033` as 27, and `0x1B` also as 27.  Using `%hd` would be consistent with the original code that used `%d`.

Comment: A more accurate statement would be "`%d` is for `int` whereas `%hd` is for `short` data types".  In fact, the distinction between `%d` and `%i` has nothing do do with `int` versus `short`.  It's the `h` modifier that matters for `short`.

Answer (score 0):

The below code passes `short *`, yet `scanf("%d...` expects an `int *`.  Using the wrong specifier/type match results in *undefined behavior*.

Your compiler should have warned of this problem. [@Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831834/short-is-not-working-but-int-does/41832692#comment70850782_41831834)

```
short a;
scanf("%d", &a); // wrong type
```

Instead use an `h` modifier to indicate a `short *`

```
scanf("%hd", &a);
```

If you are using an *old* compiler, that lacks the `h` modifier, read as an `int` and then assign.

```
int t;
scanf("%d", &t);
a = t;
```

---

BTW: best to avoid the trailing space in `" %d %d %d "`

```
//  Avoid last space
// scanf(" %d %d %d ", &a, &b, &c);

scanf("%hd %hd %hd", &a, &b, &c);
// or the following which does the same
scanf("%hd%hd%hd", &a, &b, &c);
```